# what is the difference between the given five functions that they return same output and specifically why do they return none in some of the times?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#a class is created on here
class Employee:
    raise_amount=1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
            self.k=first
            self.p=last
            self.l=pay
            self.email=first+'.'+last+'@gmail.com'
            self.h=self.email

    def fullname(self):
            return ('{} {}'.format(self.k,self.p))

    def fullname1(self):
            return print('{} {}'.format(self.k,self.p))

    def fullname2(self):
            print('{} {}'.format(self.k,self.p))

    def apply_raise(self):
            self.l=self.l*self.raise_amount


emp1= Employee('Aditya', 'Shrivastava', 5000000)
print(emp1.fullname())
print(emp1.fullname1())
emp1.fullname1()
emp1.fullname2()
print(emp1.fullname2())
```

And the output comes out to be like:

Aditya Shrivastava
Aditya Shrivastava
None
Aditya Shrivastava
Aditya Shrivastava
Aditya Shrivastava
    None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example:

```
class Employee:
    def none_funct(self):
      return print("hello")

emp1= Employee('Aditya', 'Shrivastava', 5000000)
print(emp1.none_funct())
```

it prints:

```
hello
None
```

why? think, `print` is a function that executes an action and returns `None`, so here:

```
print(emp1.none_funct())
```

inside the `print`, you have `emp1.none_funct()` that prints "hello", but returns `None`, and the outside `print`, prints that None